# Why doesn't /etc/environment work for systemd services

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, services

I've set my `PATH` in `/etc/environment`, and it works when I log in as any user, but when I run my services as any user, it doesn't respect my `/etc/environment`.
What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user logs in, the PAM libraries are called, and usually the PAM configuration calls `pam_env.so` to set up the environment for the user. This setup includes reading `/etc/environment`.

In a traditional SysVinit service startup script, you might use `su` to start a service as a non-root user; `su` would also call the PAM libraries and so would read `/etc/environment`, much like a regular user login.

But `systemd` is designed to also work in embedded systems where PAM libraries might not be present at all. So if a systemd service is configured to run as a non-root user, `systemd` will handle the environment initialization without relying on any external libraries.

See the [`ENVIRONMENT` paragraph of the `systemd.exec(5)` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment) for settings you can use in the service file to adjust the service's environment. The defaults provided by `systemd` are very minimal, so you should explicitly initialize what your service needs (which is usually a good practice).

For example, you might simply add

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
```

into your service definition.

But if your service needs to start only a few other things, it might be more robust security-wise to explicitly specify them as absolute pathnames in some configuration file, instead of relying on `PATH` which might get modified for reasons unrelated to your service, potentially causing nasty surprises.