# How to set environment variables system-wide

Tags: linux, systemd, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an environment variable in such a way that all services as well as all shells have access to these environment variables. `/etc/environment` does not seem to do that. When I set them in `/etc/environment`, systemd services are not affected.

Comment: Can you please include in your question what you're trying to do? Exactly where are you expecting a variable that isn't being set by `/etc/environment`?

Comment: I'm not sure in what way my question was unclear. I tried to make it more clear.

Comment: I see - did you try restarting after editing `/etc/environment`?

Comment: Possibly related: [Why doesn't /etc/environment work for systemd services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584080/why-doesnt-etc-environment-work-for-systemd-services)

Comment: Global environment variables can be set (see `DefaultEnvironment` in `man 5 systemd-system.conf` or `man 7 systemd.environment-generator`), but they aren't guaranteed not to be unset/ignored/overridden when a service/process starts. E.g. I see that my display manager and most of the applications in my desktop environment (KDE) don't inherit variables set in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. I guess a proper answer would require you to list the details of your specific use case.

Comment: This is almost https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/473001/5132 .